How do I match the locally listed Windows App SDK runtime version to published version?
I would like to know if I have a specific version of the Windows App SDK runtime installed.
When I go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads, I see versions listed like this:

1.6.3 (1.6.241114003)
1.6.1 (1.6.240923002)
1.6.0 (1.6.240829007)

However, when I follow the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/check-windows-app-sdk-versions and list the packages, they look nothing like this.
More specifically, if I run (get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime*).packagefullname, I see something like that:
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.6_6000.318.2304.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

How can I go from 1.6_6000.318.2304 to 1.6.3 (1.6.241114003)?

1.6.241114003 is some Microsoft internal number not meaningful to us poor mortals. We're not the only ones https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/4212

Thanks, I’ve pinged the GitHub thread.
